# Create pyqtSignals from dictionary

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-signals, qobject

Well I was scripting a software designed via Python which I'll be using signals and slots too much in an PyQt5 application. I got an idea of creating a dictionary where all signals come in and each signal will have its own key in order to access (or basically to connect it to a function). The problem is that I get this error 'AttributeError: 'PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal' object has no attribute 'connect' for some reason. I read about this error and found out that I have to declare the signals outside the constructor to get it working but unfortunately that will break my idea so that, I came here so somebody can solve my issue.

Here is the code if you still don't understand:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRunnable, pyqtSlot, QThreadPool, QObject, pyqtSignal

class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    signals = {}

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        if (kwargs is not None):
            for key, value in kwargs.items():
                self.signals[key] = value

class Worker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
```

And an example of creating signals:

```py
worker_signals = WorkerSignals(result=pyqtSignal(str), error=pyqtSignal(str))
worker_signals.signals['result'].connect(self.on_receive_result)
worker_signals.signals['error'].connect(self.on_receive_error)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As indicated in the [docs](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#unbound-and-bound-signals):

> A signal (specifically an unbound signal) is a class attribute. When a
>   signal is referenced as an attribute of an instance of the class then
>   PyQt5 automatically binds the instance to the signal in order to
>   create a bound signal. [...]

So it is not only necessary that is it declared outside the constructor but it must be a static attribute since it serves as a prototype to create the signals that belong to the instance. A possible solution is to use type to create dynamic classes:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore

d = {
    "result": QtCore.pyqtSignal(str),
    "error": QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
}

WorkerSignals = type("WorkerSignals", (QtCore.QObject,), d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    worker_signals = WorkerSignals()

    def on_result(text):
        print("result:", text)

    def on_error(text):
        print("error:", text)

    worker_signals.result.connect(on_result)
    worker_signals.error.connect(on_error)

    def emit_result():
        worker_signals.result.emit(" 1+1=2 ")
    def emit_error():
        worker_signals.error.emit(" :( ")

    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, emit_result)
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2000, emit_error)

    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(3000, app.quit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: That's not what I was looking for actually. I'm suffering from creating multiple classes for only initializing signals. I want one class only which I can just use to declare what signals are needed for a specific thread or basically dynamic signals, just like the way I did above. Thanks for promptly answering by the way.

Comment: @Mqtyx mmm, you want that objects of the same class have different signals, because that is not possible at present (in PyQt4 you could create signals as if they were attributes of the object) since PyQt5 requires that they be declared as attributes of the class (unbound signal) since internally SIP converts it into attributes of the object (bound signal). So you need it exactly you can not.

Comment: Got it. I will just carry on the normal procedure of creating signals. Thanks for your time.